# How to apply a sealed system attribute without specifying the constructor parameters each time

Tags: c#, code-analysis, c#-6.0

All my data transfer objects are instanced via reflection and thus have no constructor references. Because of this, the code analysis tool keeps generating CA1812 warnings.

I would like to apply the following system attribute to suppress these warnings for all my data transfer objects, but I really don't want to specify these parameters every time:

```
[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1812:AvoidUninstantiatedInternalClasses")]
```

So I wanted to create my own attribute `JsonDtoAttribute` that inherits `SuppressMessageAttribute` calling it with the right parameters once, so I would only have to add `[JsonDto]` in front of my data transfer classes, alas, `SuppressMessageAttribute` is sealed. I also tried to apply it to some parent class and inherit from that class, but this won't work either as `SuppressMessage` is marked as non-inherited.

Does anyone see any other way of telling *Code Analysis* to ignore CA1812 in a less verbose way?

Comment: Why not just suppress it globally?

Comment: @CodyGray right now I believe that is my best option yes, but obviously if there was a clean way of suppressing it just for these classes it would be nicer

Comment: So you're looking for a way to specify a list of classes for which that warning should not be displayed? Unfortunately, that type of granularity does not exist. You can either suppress/disable a warning globally, or you can suppress it for a particular class.

Comment: Actually that granularity does exist, you can suppress specific classes either through the attribute mentioned in the question or thorough a global suppress file at the root of the project. I just wanted to encapsulate the verbosity of these suppression lines into a cleaner simple attribute.